# How do I recover non-commited files that I lost using CleanUp command?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to Tortoise SVN. I need your help to recover 2 solidworks files I've been working on for 3 days. I need to know if it's possible to recover them. .

I copied a committed file to my desktop and made changes in the newly copied file. Then I deleted (hitting spr key) the committed file on the svn folder and moved back the desktop,  changed the file to svn but didn't commit. Then I continued working on the non-committed file on svn folder and when I finished I tried to commit the changes but a red error statement appeared and I couldn't do it.

Then a friend told me to use the Cleanup command, I selected all the checkboxes and hit continue. The folder was restored to the 3 day ago status and I lost the files I worked on.
I don't see the files in the svn folder or the trash bin even using the command revert.

Is there any way to recover my files, how?

Answer (score 0):

If the files haven't been committed or versioned there nothing to do, but take a look into **show log** option check if your files are in others revisions.

Comment: Thank you very much Abel, I checked that option and the last and only revision is the one I got with Clean UP. Do you think than maybe taking my pc to a proffesional coul'd help to recover the files from the hard drive?

Comment: Yes by restauring windows 3 days before

Answer (score 0):

If you have checkd **all** the checkboxes in the cleanup window you also selected the `Revert all changes recursively`.
This means:

> This command reverts all your local modifications which are not committed yet.
>   Note: it's better to use the TortoiseSVN → Revert command instead, because there you can first see and select the files which you want to revert.

(Taken from the [TortoiseSVN documentation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html))